# How can I get VoiceOver to announce changes to radio buttons in React?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, accessibility, voiceover

In plain HTML, creating an accessible radio button is fairly simple. When a user is using a screen reader, and checks the radio button, the screen reader announces the change.

However, I'm currently using a controlled component in React. It fires off an sync request, and when that request comes back, the radio button is then checked. This delay seems to confuse VoiceOver and it fails to announce the change.

I've tried adding the `aria-busy` attribute during the loading period and then setting it back to false at the end. This occasionally gets VoiceOver to announce the change, but the behaviour is very intermittent and typically still fails.

Here's the HTML being generated:

```
<input aria-checked="true" aria-busy="false" role="radio" type="radio" value="some_value">
```

Is there a more reliable way that I can notify the user that the radio button is now checked?

Answer (score 0):

You could try pushing a message to an `aria-live` region when the sync request comes back, and combining this with your `aria-busy` switch.

The more extreme way to ensure that the messages are read would be to use `role="alert"` which is meant for announcing errors in certain validation situations, but would work.

`aria-live` is the "polite" version of announcement that I know of at the moment, which means that the reader will wait until it has finished reading all statements in the queue before reading the live announcement.

`role="alert"` is the "rude" version of announcement that I know of, which will immediately read the message, but will also remove all messages that were before it from the queue - therefore they will not be read at all.

Hope this helps.